# What is the name for a ABC hcp lattice that is squeezed along the direction vertical to the ABC planes?

Tags: crystals, crystallography

I am trying to classify a bravais lattice. It is a hexagonaly close packed lattice with (ABC) planes, that is fcc, but it is squeezed along the stacking direction, so perpendicular to the planes. Just like ABC hexagonal close packing of smarties.